# Insert into table from another table but update if already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, insert

I'm trying to figure out how to insert/update rows inside a table.

I have two tables, real_table and temp_table, temp_table holds all the data I want to update real_table with. However, some of these rows doesn't exist inside real_table. So I want to run a command that basically insert a row if it doesn't already exist, if it does exist, update it with the new value.

The main thing I want to update is the `value` column. Here is my attempt so far:

```
INSERT INTO `real_table`(value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
FROM temp_table
VALUES (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
ON DUPLICATE UPDATE
value = temp_table.value
```

I'm getting an error though

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM temp_table VALUES (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entit' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your syntax for [insert using select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO `real_table`(value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value
FROM temp_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = temp_table.value
```

Make sure you have defined a unique index in order to take advantage of [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: It seem to have updated correctly but it's not inserting any new rows into the real_table.

Comment: @user2963379 This is because of unique attribute, Like there are no new values for unique column that is why it updates each time, It can be more clear if you can provide sample data sets for both table and table definitions would also help to identify the cause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`INSERT INTO real_table (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT temp_table
VALUES (value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)`